# Failed to restart single node etcd with data_dir mapped to persistentvolume in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, etcd, glusterfs, etcd3

Hi I am deploying an etcd container in a k8s pod with data_dir mapped to persistent volume claim created for the pod. The first time the pvc and pod is created, etcd service is up and running and everything is working as expected.

Once I delete the k8s deployment and create it again, it does recognize during bootstrap to restart existing member (may be due to non-empty data_dir) but fails to start etcd service with unexpected fault address error.

We are currently using single node etcd cluster configuration which will suffice our need of having both the service and etcd db in a single pod. One more thing, the intention of using persistentvolume is to ensure that there is no data loss between pod restarts.

etcd Version: 3.3.11

PVC.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sample-etcd-db-pvc
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: glusterfs-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-etcd-db-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-etcd-db-service
      version: 0.1.0-rc.29
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-etcd-db-service
        version: 0.1.0-rc.29
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sample-etcd-db
        image: quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.3.11
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
        - etcd
        - --name=sample-etcd-db-new
        - --listen-client-urls=http://0.0.0.0:2379
        - --advertise-client-urls=http://0.0.0.0:2379
        - --data-dir=/var/etcd/data
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/etcd/data
          name: sample-etcd-db-pvc
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2379
      volumes:
      - name: sample-etcd-db-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sample-etcd-db-pvc
```

Creating PVC and Deployment for the first time in k8s cluster

```
[root@centos-vm etcd_bug]# kubectl create -f pvc.yml
[root@centos-vm etcd_bug]# kubectl create -f deployment.yml
```

--- Trying to restart etcd by deleting and creating k8s deployment again ---

```
[root@centos-vm etcd_bug]# kubectl delete deployment sample-etcd-db-service
[root@centos-vm etcd_bug]# kubectl create -f deployment.yml

Attaching logs from the pod.
[root@centos-vm etcd_bug]# kubectl logs sample-etcd-db-service-98f4f9459-4s27f -c sample-etcd-db
2019-02-19 20:25:22.344488 I | etcdmain: etcd Version: 3.3.11
2019-02-19 20:25:22.344636 I | etcdmain: Git SHA: 2cf9e51
2019-02-19 20:25:22.344645 I | etcdmain: Go Version: go1.10.7
2019-02-19 20:25:22.344651 I | etcdmain: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2019-02-19 20:25:22.344659 I | etcdmain: setting maximum number of CPUs to 8, total number of available CPUs is 8
2019-02-19 20:25:22.348118 N | etcdmain: the server is already initialized as member before, starting as etcd member...
2019-02-19 20:25:22.348516 I | embed: listening for peers on http://0.0.0.0:2380
2019-02-19 20:25:22.349140 I | embed: listening for client requests on 0.0.0.0:2379
2019-02-19 20:25:22.391321 I | etcdserver: name = sample-etcd-db-new
2019-02-19 20:25:22.391362 I | etcdserver: data dir = /var/etcd/data
2019-02-19 20:25:22.391379 I | etcdserver: member dir = /var/etcd/data/member
2019-02-19 20:25:22.391387 I | etcdserver: heartbeat = 100ms
2019-02-19 20:25:22.391394 I | etcdserver: election = 1000ms
2019-02-19 20:25:22.391401 I | etcdserver: snapshot count = 100000
2019-02-19 20:25:22.391423 I | etcdserver: advertise client URLs = http://0.0.0.0:2379
2019-02-19 20:25:22.407858 I | etcdserver: restarting member 1c70f9bbb41018f in cluster a0d2de0531db7884 at commit index 4
2019-02-19 20:25:22.407995 I | raft: 1c70f9bbb41018f became follower at term 2
2019-02-19 20:25:22.408039 I | raft: newRaft 1c70f9bbb41018f [peers: [], term: 2, commit: 4, applied: 0, lastindex: 4, lastterm: 2]
unexpected fault address 0x7f43819ee000
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0x7f43819ee000 pc=0x8808fd]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw(0xfc556e, 0x5)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x81 fp=0xc420222ed0 sp=0xc420222eb0 pc=0x42ade1
runtime.sigpanic()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:385 +0x273 fp=0xc420222f20 sp=0xc420222ed0 pc=0x4405b3
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*DB).page(...)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/db.go:859
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Tx).page(...)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/tx.go:599
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Bucket).pageNode(0xc4202b00f8, 0x2, 0x18, 0xc4201b78e0)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/bucket.go:724 +0xad fp=0xc420222f98 sp=0xc420222f20 pc=0x8808fd
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Cursor).search(0xc420223138, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7, 0x2)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/cursor.go:254 +0x50 fp=0xc420223050 sp=0xc420222f98 pc=0x881d90
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Cursor).seek(0xc420223138, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4, 0xc4201bc8c0, 0x1, 0x1, ...)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/cursor.go:159 +0xa5 fp=0xc4202230a0 sp=0xc420223050 pc=0x881695
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Bucket).CreateBucket(0xc4202b00f8, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/bucket.go:165 +0xfa fp=0xc4202231a0 sp=0xc4202230a0 pc=0x87dc6a
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Tx).CreateBucket(0xc4202b00e0, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7, 0x2, 0x1c70f9bbb41018f, 0x4)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/tx.go:108 +0x4f fp=0xc4202231e8 sp=0xc4202231a0 pc=0x88cbcf
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend.(*batchTx).UnsafeCreateBucket(0xc4201be6f0, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend/batch_tx.go:48 +0x6b fp=0xc420223280 sp=0xc4202231e8 pc=0x8de51b
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/membership.mustCreateBackendBuckets(0x10b3700, 0xc4201bb9d0)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/membership/store.go:166 +0xb7 fp=0xc4202232c0 sp=0xc420223280 pc=0x957827
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/membership.(*RaftCluster).SetBackend(0xc4201ce720, 0x10b3700, 0xc4201bb9d0)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/membership/cluster.go:203 +0x54 fp=0xc4202232e0 sp=0xc4202232c0 pc=0x9525f4
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver.NewServer(0x7ffee163af6a, 0x12, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc4201a1200, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc4201a1100, ...)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/server.go:396 +0x921 fp=0xc420223ab0 sp=0xc4202232e0 pc=0xb762e1
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/embed.StartEtcd(0xc420294000, 0xc420294480, 0x0, 0x0)
.....

[root@centos-vm etcd_bug]# kubectl logs sample-etcd-db-service-98f4f9459-4s27f -c sample-etcd-db
2019-02-19 20:36:20.383231 I | etcdmain: etcd Version: 3.3.11
2019-02-19 20:36:20.383404 I | etcdmain: Git SHA: 2cf9e51
2019-02-19 20:36:20.383413 I | etcdmain: Go Version: go1.10.7
2019-02-19 20:36:20.383419 I | etcdmain: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2019-02-19 20:36:20.383434 I | etcdmain: setting maximum number of CPUs to 8, total number of available CPUs is 8
2019-02-19 20:36:20.386048 N | etcdmain: the server is already initialized as member before, starting as etcd member...
2019-02-19 20:36:20.386987 I | embed: listening for peers on http://localhost:2380
2019-02-19 20:36:20.388330 I | embed: listening for client requests on 0.0.0.0:2379
2019-02-19 20:36:20.437097 I | etcdserver: name = sample-etcd-db-new
2019-02-19 20:36:20.437177 I | etcdserver: data dir = /var/etcd/data
2019-02-19 20:36:20.437198 I | etcdserver: member dir = /var/etcd/data/member
2019-02-19 20:36:20.437211 I | etcdserver: heartbeat = 100ms
2019-02-19 20:36:20.437222 I | etcdserver: election = 1000ms
2019-02-19 20:36:20.437233 I | etcdserver: snapshot count = 100000
2019-02-19 20:36:20.437284 I | etcdserver: advertise client URLs = http://0.0.0.0:2379
2019-02-19 20:36:20.456385 I | etcdserver: restarting member 1c70f9bbb41018f in cluster a0d2de0531db7884 at commit index 4
2019-02-19 20:36:20.456489 I | raft: 1c70f9bbb41018f became follower at term 2
2019-02-19 20:36:20.456520 I | raft: newRaft 1c70f9bbb41018f [peers: [], term: 2, commit: 4, applied: 0, lastindex: 4, lastterm: 2]
unexpected fault address 0x7efabfc3e000
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0x7efabfc3e000 pc=0x8808fd]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw(0xfc556e, 0x5)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x81 fp=0xc420258ed0 sp=0xc420258eb0 pc=0x42ade1
runtime.sigpanic()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:385 +0x273 fp=0xc420258f20 sp=0xc420258ed0 pc=0x4405b3
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*DB).page(...)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/db.go:859
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Tx).page(...)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/tx.go:599
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Bucket).pageNode(0xc4203220f8, 0x2, 0x18, 0xc420227580)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/bucket.go:724 +0xad fp=0xc420258f98 sp=0xc420258f20 pc=0x8808fd
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Cursor).search(0xc420259138, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7, 0x2)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/cursor.go:254 +0x50 fp=0xc420259050 sp=0xc420258f98 pc=0x881d90
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Cursor).seek(0xc420259138, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4, 0xc4202287f0, 0x1, 0x1, ...)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/cursor.go:159 +0xa5 fp=0xc4202590a0 sp=0xc420259050 pc=0x881695
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Bucket).CreateBucket(0xc4203220f8, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/bucket.go:165 +0xfa fp=0xc4202591a0 sp=0xc4202590a0 pc=0x87dc6a
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt.(*Tx).CreateBucket(0xc4203220e0, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7, 0x2, 0x1c70f9bbb41018f, 0x4)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/bbolt/tx.go:108 +0x4f fp=0xc4202591e8 sp=0xc4202591a0 pc=0x88cbcf
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend.(*batchTx).UnsafeCreateBucket(0xc420240b40, 0x16062d0, 0x7, 0x7)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend/batch_tx.go:48 +0x6b fp=0xc420259280 sp=0xc4202591e8 pc=0x8de51b
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/membership.mustCreateBackendBuckets(0x10b3700, 0xc4202c8620)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/membership/store.go:166 +0xb7 fp=0xc4202592c0 sp=0xc420259280 pc=0x957827
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/membership.(*RaftCluster).SetBackend(0xc42022a960, 0x10b3700, 0xc4202c8620)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/membership/cluster.go:203 +0x54 fp=0xc4202592e0 sp=0xc4202592c0 pc=0x9525f4
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver.NewServer(0x7fff206f1fa8, 0x12, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc420280a00, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc420280700, ...)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/server.go:396 +0x921 fp=0xc420259ab0 sp=0xc4202592e0 pc=0xb762e1
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/embed.StartEtcd(0xc4202da000, 0xc4202da480, 0x0, 0x0)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/embed/etcd.go:179 +0x811 fp=0xc42025a6e8 sp=0xc420259ab0 pc=0xcb6361
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdmain.startEtcd(0xc4202da000, 0xfc6677, 0x6, 0xc42025ad01, 0x2)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdmain/etcd.go:181 +0x40 fp=0xc42025a7b0 sp=0xc42025a6e8 pc=0xd263c0
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdmain.startEtcdOrProxyV2()
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdmain/etcd.go:102 +0x1369 fp=0xc42025bf08 sp=0xc42025a7b0 pc=0xd25d79
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdmain.Main()
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdmain/main.go:46 +0x3f fp=0xc42025bf78 sp=0xc42025bf08 pc=0xd2c81f
main.main()
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/etcd/main.go:28 +0x20 fp=0xc42025bf88 sp=0xc42025bf78 pc=0xd2e910
runtime.main()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:198 +0x212 fp=0xc42025bfe0 sp=0xc42025bf88 pc=0x42c652
runtime.goexit()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361 +0x1 fp=0xc42025bfe8 sp=0xc42025bfe0 pc=0x459f81

goroutine 51 [chan receive]:
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil.(*MergeLogger).outputLoop(0xc4201c3720)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil/merge_logger.go:174 +0x40d
created by github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil.NewMergeLogger
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil/merge_logger.go:92 +0x85

goroutine 104 [chan receive]:
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil.(*MergeLogger).outputLoop(0xc420262680)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil/merge_logger.go:174 +0x40d
created by github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil.NewMergeLogger
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil/merge_logger.go:92 +0x85

goroutine 72 [chan receive]:
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil.(*MergeLogger).outputLoop(0xc420224860)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil/merge_logger.go:174 +0x40d
created by github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil.NewMergeLogger
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/logutil/merge_logger.go:92 +0x85

goroutine 116 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:139 +0xa6
os/signal.loop()
/usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x22
created by os/signal.init.0
/usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x41

goroutine 91 [select]:
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/wal.(*filePipeline).run(0xc42023fb00)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/wal/file_pipeline.go:89 +0x139
created by github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/wal.newFilePipeline
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/wal/file_pipeline.go:47 +0x11a

goroutine 90 [select]:
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend.(*backend).run(0xc4202c8620)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend/backend.go:267 +0x180
created by github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend.newBackend
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend/backend.go:161 +0x2ea

goroutine 92 [select]:
github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/raft.(*node).run(0xc42022a9c0, 0xc4202d4100)
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/raft/node.go:313 +0x5f8
created by github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/raft.RestartNode
/tmp/etcd-release-3.3.11/etcd/release/etcd/gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/cmd/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/raft/node.go:223 +0x321
```

Comment: It's just caused by a corrupted database, [and is apparently happening a lot](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+bolt+panic) but any `etcd` member can reacquire the correct database from the other members -- so just delete that directory and have the new member sync it fresh. I would _guess_ there's some nastiness going on with glusterfs not syncing the changes, resulting in corruption, but solving THAT would be some work.

Comment: I wrote out that comment before seeing "We are currently using single node etcd cluster configuration" in which case you are taking your etcd-life into your own hands; don't do that.